# how to block vertical swipe movement in UIScrollView in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiscrollview

i have an Image carousel in my app
i use a `UIScrollView` to show the images inside.
everything works fine, it's just that i want to know how do i block up movements in the `UIScrollView`

for now the user can just swipe the picture up.. and i want to block it
i tried doing some fixed but none seems to work now maybe it's something in my code ?

here is my complete view controller for the `UIScrollView`:

```
class CaruselleScreenViewController: UIViewController, CaruselleScreenViewProtocol, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    var slides:[CaruselleTipsCard] = [];

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        slides = createSlides()
        setupSlideScrollView(slides: slides)

        pageControl.numberOfPages = slides.count
        pageControl.currentPage = 0
        view.bringSubview(toFront: pageControl)


        //adds dots
        scrollView.delegate = self

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    func createSlides() -> [CaruselleTipsCard] {

        let slide1:CaruselleTipsCard = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CaruselleTipsCard", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! CaruselleTipsCard
        slide1.mainPic.image = UIImage(named: "backlightingIllo")

        //
        let slide2:CaruselleTipsCard = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CaruselleTipsCard", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! CaruselleTipsCard
        slide2.mainPic.image = UIImage(named: "comfortableIllo")

        //
        let slide3:CaruselleTipsCard = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CaruselleTipsCard", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! CaruselleTipsCard
        slide3.mainPic.image = UIImage(named: "pharmacyIllo")

        //
        let slide4:CaruselleTipsCard = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CaruselleTipsCard", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! CaruselleTipsCard
        slide4.mainPic.image = UIImage(named: "batteryIllo")

        //
        let slide5:CaruselleTipsCard = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CaruselleTipsCard", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! CaruselleTipsCard
        slide5.mainPic.image = UIImage(named: "wiFiIllo")



        return [slide1, slide2, slide3, slide4, slide5]
    }

    func setupSlideScrollView(slides : [CaruselleTipsCard]) {
        scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width * CGFloat(slides.count), height: view.frame.height)
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true

        for i in 0 ..< slides.count {
            slides[i].frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.width * CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
            scrollView.addSubview(slides[i])
        }
    }


    //////

    /*
     * default function called when view is scolled. In order to enable callback
     * when scrollview is scrolled, the below code needs to be called:
     * slideScrollView.delegate = self or
     */
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let pageIndex = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x/view.frame.width)
        pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageIndex)

        let maximumHorizontalOffset: CGFloat = scrollView.contentSize.width - scrollView.frame.width
        let currentHorizontalOffset: CGFloat = scrollView.contentOffset.x

        // vertical
        let maximumVerticalOffset: CGFloat = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.height
        let currentVerticalOffset: CGFloat = scrollView.contentOffset.y

        let percentageHorizontalOffset: CGFloat = currentHorizontalOffset / maximumHorizontalOffset
        let percentageVerticalOffset: CGFloat = currentVerticalOffset / maximumVerticalOffset


        /*
         * below code changes the background color of view on paging the scrollview
         */
        //        self.scrollView(scrollView, didScrollToPercentageOffset: percentageHorizontalOffset)


        /*
         * below code scales the imageview on paging the scrollview
         */
        let percentOffset: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: percentageHorizontalOffset, y: percentageVerticalOffset)

        if(percentOffset.x > 0 && percentOffset.x <= 0.25) {

            slides[0].mainPic.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: (0.25-percentOffset.x)/0.25, y: (0.25-percentOffset.x)/0.25)
            slides[1].mainPic.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: percentOffset.x/0.25, y: percentOffset.x/0.25)

        } else if(percentOffset.x > 0.25 && percentOffset.x <= 0.50) {
            slides[1].mainPic.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: (0.50-percentOffset.x)/0.25, y: (0.50-percentOffset.x)/0.25)
            slides[2].mainPic.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: percentOffset.x/0.50, y: percentOffset.x/0.50)

        } else if(percentOffset.x > 0.50 && percentOffset.x <= 0.75) {
            slides[2].mainPic.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: (0.75-percentOffset.x)/0.25, y: (0.75-percentOffset.x)/0.25)
            slides[3].mainPic.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: percentOffset.x/0.75, y: percentOffset.x/0.75)

        } else if(percentOffset.x > 0.75 && percentOffset.x <= 1) {
            slides[3].mainPic.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: (1-percentOffset.x)/0.25, y: (1-percentOffset.x)/0.25)
            slides[4].mainPic.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: percentOffset.x, y: percentOffset.x)
        }
    }

}
```

can you tell me how to block vertical swipe ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this,

```
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    scrollView.contentSize  = CGSize(width: scrollView.contentSize.width, height: 0) //disable vertical
```

Comment: the prolem with that sulotion is that i cannot later do scrollView.scrollRectToVisible becouse it blocks it for some wierd reason

Comment: you can redo the content size when you do scroll rect to visible to the default incase you need it just put a flag and check on it